# On Populus I am unable to make Basic Testing (Greeter Contract) work due to py.test

Tags: greeter, populus, web3.py

I was not able to make the following [Basic Testing](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.part-1.html) example work on populus.

- platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32,
  pluggy-0.4.0 rootdir: /Users/avatar/populus, inifile:
- plugins: populus-1.4.2
- OS: tried on mac OS and Linux.

-

```
[$] mkdir populus && cd populus
[$] populus init 
Created Directory: ./contracts
Created Example Contract: ./contracts/Greeter.sol
Created Directory: ./tests
Created Example Tests: ./tests/test_greeter.py

[~/pop]$ populus compile

============ Compiling ==============
> Loading source files from: ./contracts
> Found 1 contract source files
- contracts/Greeter.sol
> Compiled 1 contracts
- Greeter
> Wrote compiled assets to: ./build/contracts.json

[$] pytest tests/test_greeter.py //does not work ...
```

Following error emerged:

---

```
_____ test_greeter ______________________________________________________________________________

chain = <populus.chain.EthereumTesterChain object at 0x10db60610>

    def test_greeter(chain):
>       greeter = chain.get_contract('Greeter')

tests/test_greeter.py:2:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:566: in get_contract
    registrar = self.registrar
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/utils/functional.py:50: in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:533: in registrar
    deploy_txn_hash = self.RegistrarFactory.deploy()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:206: in RegistrarFactory
    return get_registrar(self.web3)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

web3 = <web3.main.Web3 object at 0x10db60f50>, address = None

    def get_registrar(web3, address=None):
        registrar_contract_data = get_compiled_registrar_contract()
        return web3.eth.contract(
            address=address,
            abi=registrar_contract_data['abi'],
>           code=registrar_contract_data['code'],
            code_runtime=registrar_contract_data['code_runtime'],
        )
E       KeyError: 'code'

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/migrations/registrar.py:51: KeyError
__________________________________________________________________________ test_custom_greeting __________________________________________________________________________

chain = <populus.chain.EthereumTesterChain object at 0x10df08d10>

    def test_custom_greeting(chain):
>       greeter = chain.get_contract('Greeter')

tests/test_greeter.py:9:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:566: in get_contract
    registrar = self.registrar
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/utils/functional.py:50: in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:533: in registrar
    deploy_txn_hash = self.RegistrarFactory.deploy()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:206: in RegistrarFactory
    return get_registrar(self.web3)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

web3 = <web3.main.Web3 object at 0x10df08c90>, address = None

    def get_registrar(web3, address=None):
        registrar_contract_data = get_compiled_registrar_contract()
        return web3.eth.contract(
            address=address,
            abi=registrar_contract_data['abi'],
>           code=registrar_contract_data['code'],
            code_runtime=registrar_contract_data['code_runtime'],
        )
E       KeyError: 'code'

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/migrations/registrar.py:51: KeyError
```

As recommendation Version 0.6 is downloaded from here: https://github.com/pipermerriam/py-solc/tree/v0.6.0 and inside downloaded folder I did: `python setup.py install`. Also `py-solc` version 0.9 and 0.9.1 is tried.

I would so grateful if you could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I bet my left testicle this is some sort of version incompatibility issue. I poked Piper on Gitter.im chat http://gitter.im/pipermerriam/populus to see if he can confirm this issue.

Comment: Yes,  If you pin `py-solc<=1.7.0` things should start working.  Alternatively you can be brave and start using `populus==1.5.0-beta.1`.

Comment: I did `pip install py-solc==0.9.1` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just adding the answer from the above comments, so that this question can be closed:*

`sudo pip install --upgrade populus` should solve this problem. Although no one is likely to have this specific issue anymore.